# mongodb modelling relationships

Tags: mongodb

My question is how to best model three objects that are related by combinations of 1 to many and many to many relationships. For example, in a medical clinic, a patient can see many doctors, and a doctor can treat many patients, a doctor may recommend many tests for a patient, a test is always for one patient and a patient may have many tests.  Here is what I am favoring, embedding tests within patient:

Patients:

```
{
   _id: ObjectID
   patient_name: String
   insurance: String
   Doctors: [
       doctor_name: String
   ]
   Tests:   [
    { test_name: string; test_result:string; doctor_name: string }
   ]
}
```

Doctors:

```
{
   _id: ObjectID
   doctor_name: String
   Specialty: String
   patients: [ patient_name: String ]
}
```

The problem with this is doctor name may be duplicated in patient/doctors and patient/tests, if tests is embedded as above. The other approach considered is having three collections: patients, doctors and tests so that tests is not embedded in patients.  The problem with this approach is when someone wants to look at a patient's chart, they will want to see the test results and that means more reads.  What are some guidelines on the best way to model such a problem in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, it heavily depends on your use cases. Let us assume a couple of simple ones:

1. You want to list all patients of a **given** doctor
2. You want to list all doctors who treated a **given** patient
3. You want to list all tests that were administered to a **given** patient.
4. You want to list all tests that were ordered by a **given** doctor to a **given** patient.
5. You want to list all tests ordered by a **given** doctor.

The "**given**" is not highlighted by accident. It denotes the information you already have at the time of the query.

### Patients

You correctly identified that the doctor's relations to their patients should be saved inside the patient document

As for the patients, we would need an array of doctors. But doctors may have the same name. Think of John Miller. So how can we positively identify any given John Miller? Right, by an unique ID. And hey, by default you need one for every MonogDB document anyway. So, lets start with a simple model:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  doctors: [ObjectId, ObjectId, ObjectId...],
}
```

But then, we immediately see a problem: You want to display the doctors names when showing a patient, right? With the data model above, you'd have to do something like:

```
var patient = db.patient.find(some_query)
var patientsDoctors = db.doctors.find({_id:{$in:"$patient.doctors"}})
```

In this use case, that might even be a viable solution, since the doctor's `_id` fields are indexed anyway (so the second query should be reasonably fast), and the array `$patient.doctors` is rather small. However, if you want to save that query, we have to trade (relatively cheap) disk space against (relatively hard to acquire) performance by changing our data model slightly:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  doctors: [
    {id:ObjectId,name: String},
    {id:ObjectId,name: String},
    {id:ObjectId,name: String},
  ...]
}
```

Now, when you show a patient, you can list the doctors names right away. In case a more detailed view of the doctor is needed, you can positively identify the doctor in question by his or her `_id` and deal with the presentation accordingly.

Now finding all patients who were treated by a given doctor becomes easy enough:

```
db.patients.find({"doctors.id": someObjectId})
```

However, there is still a problem: This query will actually result in a [collection scan](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/indexes-introduction/), meaning each document in the collection will be read and compared against your query criteria. Slow and hence bad. We need to create an index:

```
db.patients.createIndex({"doctors.id":1})
```

and the [result of `.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) looks like what we want to have:

```
> db.patients.find({"doctors.id":ObjectId("58c4fdf5b5aeccb7a2bfe727")}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "clinic.patients",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "doctors.id" : {
                "$eq" : ObjectId("58c4fdf5b5aeccb7a2bfe727")
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "doctors.id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "doctors.id_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "doctors.id" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "doctors.id" : [
                        "[ObjectId('58c4fdf5b5aeccb7a2bfe727'), ObjectId('58c4fdf5b5aeccb7a2bfe727')]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
  // serverInfo ommited for brevity here
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But now what happens if a doctor changes his or her name? Albeit this probably is a rare use case (marriages and gender changes, mainly), we need to address that. But since this use case *is* rare, we can live with a relatively slow query to address it:

```
db.patients.update(
  {"doctors.id":ObjectId("58c4fdf5b5aeccb7a2bfe727")},
  {"$set":{"doctors.$.name":"Bar Baz"}},
  {multi:true}
)
```

Now it seems we have our use case 1 modelled and use case 2 is already done, too ;)

### Tests

The main question is wether we should store the tests inside the patient or have their own collection or similar to what we did with the doctors. That is a matter of believe and requirements. Personally, I would store the tests like this:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  patient: ObjectId,
  doctor: ObjectId,
  description: String,
  date: ISODate,
  // whatever you deem appropriate
}
```

This way, we can handle the remaining 3 use cases:

#### All tests for a given patient

```
var patient = db.patient.find(someQuery)
var testsForPatient  = db.tests.find({patient:"patient._id"})
```

You already have the patient and the test, now you only have to load the doctor's data additionally. In case you wish, you can add the doctor's name here, too, according to how we did it in the patient's model.

#### Tests ordered by a given doctor and a given patient

```
var doctor = db.doctors.find(someQueryForDoctor)
var patient = db.patients.find(someQueryForPatient)
var testsOfDoctorOnPatient = db.tests.find({patient:"$patient._id",doctor:"$doctor._id"})
```

You already have both the patient's and the doctor's details, so there is no need to embed any information for this use case.

#### Tests ordered by a given doctor

```
var doctor = db.doctors.find(someQueryForDoctor)
var testsofDoctor = db.tests.find({doctor:"$doctor._id"})
```

Since you most likely need queries like this for statistical purposes, it does not make sense to embed the patient's details to a test.

#### Indexing for Tests

Without indexing, the queries on the tests will result in a collection scan, again. But how would we index here. Since we are searching either by the doctor's `_id` or the patient's `_id` or *both*, a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) comes in handy:

```
db.tests.createIndex({patient:1,doctor:1})
```

With this index, all queries on the tests collection mentioned above utilise an index, as you can verify yourself using the [***`.explain()`***](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) method.

### Conclusion

It is of utmost importance that you ask yourself what given data you have and which data you want to query for. A good example is actually querying the tests for a given patient. Do you *really* need the doctor's name right away or would a button like "Ordered by" be sufficient for your use case?

Another rule of thumb is: document what happened at a given point in time and only embed what you absolutely need.

Hope this lengthy example helps you understanding on how to approach data modelling in MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you for your outstanding reply.